# Deep Linking to Android and iOS apps in Facebook

Tags: android, ios, facebook

I'm editing Call-to-Action Button (Use App) on Facebook fanpage and I want to add Deep Link to Google Play Store. I fill Deep Link field with following data: `market://details?id=pl.app.xxxxxx` and I get: 
`Please add a valid URL` error.

What is a correct deep link format on Facebook for Android and iOS apps?